# Can we create styles.xml file by programmatically(.java class) in Android?

Tags: android, material-design

I want to create `styles.xml` file by programmatically I meant from `.java` class.

I wanna pass argument so I can change item value in `style.xml` at runtime.

Comment: why do you need to create a style at run time. May be we can suggest you a better approach

Comment: I am developing one cordova plugin for digits and digits only allows change from styles.xml thats why I need runtime styles.xml .
So single plugin can be used in different application , we just need to pass argument

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible. All application resources (including `styles.xml`) are not modifiable on runtime. If you want to allow user to change theme or `Toolbar` color do it programmatically and save user preferences in `SharedPreferences`.